# Why UIButton showing selected state when turning page over

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uibutton

I would like to change the state of a UIButton, only when it appears on a certain page (with `currentIndex`).  But when navigating to the next page, my UIButton shows the same `selectedState` rather than changing.

Here is my implemented code:

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkState:(id)sender {

currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];
if (_BookmarkState != _bookmarkbtn.tag)   {
    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"]
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self setBookmarkState:NO]; 
    [contentViewController.bookmarks removeIndex:currentIndex];

    } 
    else {

    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];     

    [self setBookmarkState:YES]; 
    [contentViewController.bookmarks addIndex:currentIndex];
    }
}
```

How can i fix this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is wrong with your code:

- You define `currentIndex` but neither read again it nor change the array where it comes from.
- You are changing an array with bookmarks, but you never read it.
- You compare the tag of an object called `_bookmarkbtn`, presumably a button, with another object that looks like some weird kind of class (initial capital letter) but is probably a constant.
- Therefore, you are **not** using currentIndex, and **not** comparing anything that refers to the `sender` of the button action.

Maybe you intended to compare the right element of your bookmarks array to the `tag` of the button that was pressed? Your code does not do this.

Maybe a straight-forward way is to simply set the correct the image of the button whenever the page appears and just toggle it whenever the button is pressed.